# rvest empty list for table via xpath

Tags: r, xpath, web-scraping

I need help for scraping data from the website below. I copied how the link here does https://msperlin.github.io/pafdR/importingInternet.html#accessing-data-from-web-pages-webscraping to get the table of rates down but i get only list 0. Can someone please help me?

```
library(rvest)

# set url and xpath
my.url <- 'https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield'
my.xpath <- '//*[@id="t-content-main-content"]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div/table'


# get nodes from html
out.nodes <- html_nodes(read_html(my.url),
                        xpath = my.xpath)

# get table from nodes (each element in 
# list is a table)
df <- html_table(out.nodes)
df
```

Answer (score 2):

It's usually better to not use extremely precise XPath statements since the structure of pages can change and sometimes what looks correct in the browser source or Developer Tools may not be (browsers modify HTML when they read it in).

Using said Developer Tools (in this case via Firefox but Chrome shld work fine too), an Inspect Element near the table shows:

[image]

We can just stick with CSS selector syntax and do:

```
library(rvest)

pg <- read_html("https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/data-chart-center/interest-rates/Pages/TextView.aspx?data=yield")

html_node(pg, "table.t-chart") %>% 
  html_table()
##       Date 1 mo 3 mo 6 mo 1 yr 2 yr 3 yr 5 yr 7 yr 10 yr 20 yr 30 yr
## 1 10/01/18 2.13 2.23 2.40 2.60 2.82 2.90 2.96 3.04  3.09  3.18  3.24
## 2 10/02/18 2.14 2.23 2.41 2.61 2.82 2.88 2.94 3.01  3.05  3.14  3.20
## 3 10/03/18 2.15 2.23 2.41 2.62 2.85 2.94 3.02 3.10  3.15  3.24  3.30
## 4 10/04/18 2.16 2.22 2.42 2.63 2.87 2.97 3.05 3.14  3.19  3.29  3.35
## 5 10/05/18 2.15 2.23 2.41 2.64 2.88 2.99 3.07 3.18  3.23  3.34  3.40
```

In this case CSS selectors are easier (that's not always the case) but you can also use XPath queries as well:

```
html_node(pg, xpath = ".//table[@class='t-chart']")
```